# named routing doesnt work in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Hey, I want to name my route using the `:as` parameter. Ive read the Rails Routing Guide about this but unfortunately it wont display me `/my_courses` in the url

```
match 'course_enrollments', :to => 'course_enrollments#index', :as => 'my_courses'
```

thx for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match 'my_courses', :to => 'course_enrollments#index', :as => 'my_courses'`

This will route `/my_courses` to the index action of your CourseEnrollments controller, and allow you to refer to the path by referencing `my_courses_path` or `my_courses_url` in your views and controllers.

To clarify: The first parameter in match is what maps the route to an actual URL. The `:as` option simply allows you to override the name of the route helper.

Answer (score 0):

That matches `course_enrollments` in the URL, not `my_courses`. The `:as` parameter means you can refer to the route in views using (in this example) `my_courses_path`.

Comment: it says: my_courses_path cant be found. I just want to change the url from `/course_enrollsments` to `/my_courses`. I thought this could the way. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: While this answer does tell @DannyRe what is wrong, it does not offer a solution.